# Need some info about JWT Authentication for REST APIs

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, jwt

I need to secure my REST API, for that i used JWT authentication on a simple REST API. After accomplishing JWT Authentication i needed answers to some questions, it will be great if any one can help me out here. Following are the questions:

1. How is token based authentication more secure than basic authentication?
2. What is the Criteria of Checking the validity of token?
3. What is the Algorithm for token generation is JWT?
4. Where/How is the token being compared/Verified?

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction/ is a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

1. For question 1: Both are not secure than the other. Infact both are equally vulnerable to attcks (pls research a more on this). The advantage of jwt is that you can store the proof of authorization on the client (and yes its secure as its signed by your secret). But in case of sessions, they take up server space.
2. For question 2: The process of validity is upto the implementation. You can have an expiry defined for the token and invalidate the session once the token expires or you can use a refresh token to issue a new token. The validation process involves decoding the token with your secret (with which the token was signed before issuing it to the client).
3. For question 3: The general algorithm involved in encoding is base64 and that in signing is HS256 with a secret key. Other algorithms are also used in different implementations.
4. For question 4: The client should add the token for each protected request to the server (stating the authorization of the client). The initial process in the server would be to verify the token and find who sent the request. So the process of verification is done at the server.

At the end all you have to remember is that jwt is a proof for authorization and for authentication you could go for a username password based security by which you could issue the token of authorization.